# Compiling VS2012 Application to .exe without any sort of installer

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, exe, publish

Is there a way to publish a VS2012 App (WPF) to an .exe without any installer? I know how to use ClickOnce installers but i was wondering if it could be taken one step furthur.

Many small programs seem to come in a .rar with some app files and an .exe that runs and doesn't have to install. Is this possible in VS2012? (or 2010)

Comment: is .net installed on the target machine? do you have any 3rd party dependencies?

Comment: @DanielA.White I would probably distribute it on Vista and above, so yes. XP doesn't have .NET, right? And it isn't for a particular project, just curious - but yes, I do have third party libraries on some projects.

Comment: it depends on the version of .net/windows combo you are trying to target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, sure, it's possible.  Just compile you app in Release mode and take all you have in Release folder.

Comment: @Wilson you got to make sure the right .net version is installed!

Comment: @Daniel A. White How can I do so while still using a standalone? Are .NET versions the same on all XP installations, etc?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with Visual Studio 2012 depending on your needs and your approach to developing your application. I'll list a couple options, but don't take this as being exhaustive as there are many ways to accomplish the same thing. I'm assuming you want a "1 click" solution for the user.

1. You can [embed all of your application's resources](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292) into the application allowing your users to be able to simply download or copy the .exe and run it from anywhere and it "just works".

Pros: The only method that gives you what you asked for. A single .exe without the need for an installer.

Cons: You can't edit any of the embedded resources without a recompilation of the application. You also can't store user settings for this same reason (though you could silently create a settings file in `App_Data` or similar).

1. [Self extracting archive](http://www.jackmccarthy.com/malware/WinRAR_Archive_Creation.htm). This is the WinRAR method you mentioned in your question. You embed your application into a self-extracting archive which is set to extract to the users Temp directory or App_Data (or similar) and to launch your exe upon successful extraction.

Pros: You get the ability to update your resources as they aren't embedded into your actual application.

Cons: Technically, this is still an installer; albeit a very lightweight and self-contained one.

There are more, such as click-once; etc., but this explained the general idea.

**Note:** The correct .NET version will need to be installed for these to work as simply as I described.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the concerns I can think of that an installer takes care of that you would need to worry about:

1. The correct .NET framework already exists.
2. Any assemblies that you reference from the GAC are already installed.
3. You don't need any custom registry entries or permissions to be granted.
4. Your app doesn't access anything that would keep it from working in a "low trust" environment when the user is not running as admin.

There are surely more, but basically if your app is self-contained and does not use any external resources and the correct .NET framework is installed, you should be able to just copy your build output and go.